# Keep a method from obfuscate in android

Tags: android, obfuscation

I want to keep a method from obfuscating and rename.

```
package test.app.my;

class my {
    public  void done() {

    }
}
```

Comment: And what the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During build, obfuscation is handled by the build step that invokes Proguard, so to keep a method you add to your Proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class test.app.my {
    void done();
}
```

The configuration syntax supports wildcards and is quite powerful - take a look at some [examples from the Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html).